# Qual a diferença entre Reverse Proxy e Forward Proxy?

Tags: proxy

Estou buscando a resposta para esta pergunta, mas a maioria das fontes que consultei, incluindo o próprio Stack Overflow em inglês, não solucionaram a minha dúvida.

Comment: Vou positivar e favoritar porque essa pergunta é muito interessante pra comunidade, penso que mesmo que exista no SOen a resposta, é legal trazer o conteudo pro nosso site. +1

Answer (score -1):

Simples, a diferença entre um e outro é que o *Forward Proxy* é usado para proteger os clientes dentro de uma determinada rede interna, ou seja, filtra os pacotes vindo de redes externas.
Já o *Reverse Proxy* faz o contrário, que é proteger servidores dos clientes; filtrando os pacotes vindo da rede interna (clientes) para a externa (servidores).